# How to check a RefreshIndicator state to take actions based on its state value?

Tags: dart, flutter

I mean checking if the refresh indicator is refreshing or not. to take action based on that value to stop the Spinner from spinning when the value is true.

```
 Widget _productLogic(MainModel model) {
  Widget content = Center(
    child: Text("No products available."),
  );
  if (model.allProduct.length > 0 && !model.isLoading) {
    content = _buildProductList(model.allProduct);
  } else if (model.isLoading) {
    content = Center(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    );
  }
  return RefreshIndicator(
      child: content,
      onRefresh: model.fetchProducts,
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      color: Colors.red);
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return ScopedModelDescendant<MainModel>(
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child, MainModel model) {
    return _productLogic(model);
  });
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BG4I0.png)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have to set **Global Key** to `RefreshIndicator` and check `currentState` like below

```
  final GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState> _refreshKey =
      new GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>();
```

Then

```
 return RefreshIndicator(
        key: _refreshKey,
```

And Then

```
_refreshKey.currentState?.show()?.then((_) {......
```